# React Native avoid {width: '100%'} by default

Tags: react-native, layout

My code is pretty simple: (relevant parts shown only)

```
<ScrollView style={{/* padding, centering... */}>
  <Text>SHARE WITH YOU FRIENDS</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Yet, when I inspect the Text node, its width is 100% of its container, and the grey background goes all the width.

Is there a layout setting to make this Text's width as small as possible? I.e. only until the end of the Text.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Scroll` view you can try like

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
    <Text >SHARE WITH YOU FRIENDS</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 19):

You can use [alignSelf](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignself) property:

```
<View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}> 
    <Text>SHARE WITH YOU FRIENDS</Text>
</View>
```